# Joining a column from another table with InnoDB engine

Tags: mysql, innodb, join

I'm using MySQL with InnoDB and I want to join the location column from products table into a productStock table. I have this table 'products'

```
mysql> select * from products;
+-----------+-------------------+-------+-------+-------------------------+-------+------------------+-------------+
| productID | product_reference | brand | model | productName|price|product_description | location    |+-----------+-------------------+-------+-------+-------------------------+-------+---------------------+-------------+
|         1 | 0001              | HP    | 6800  | Cartridge Plotter Z6100 | 40.00 | HP INK CARTRIDGE    | Container 1 |
|         2 | 0002              | HP    | 7550  | HP INK CARTRIDGE YELLOW | 10.00 | HP INK CARTRIDGE    | Container 2 |
|         3 | 0003              | HP    | 8600  | HP INK CARTRIDGE CYAN   |  5.00 | HP INK CARTRIDGE    | Container 1 |
|         4 | 0004              | HP    | 8640  | HP INK CARTRIDGE RED    |  5.99 | HP INK CARTRIDGE    | Container 2 |
+-----------+-------------------+-------+-------+-------------------------+-------+---------------------+-------------+
```

and second table productStock

```
mysql> select * from productStock;
+----+-----------+-------------------+-------------------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------------+
| id | productID | product_reference | productName             | brand | model | physicalStock | lowStockAlert | lastUpdatedBy | lastUpdateDate      |
+----+-----------+-------------------+-------------------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------------+
|  1 |         1 | 0001              | Cartridge Plotter Z6100 | HP    | 6800  |            33 |             0 | steven        | 2014-09-25 13:36:35 |
|  2 |         2 | 0002              | HP INK CARTRIDGE YELLOW | HP    | 7550  |            20 |             0 | osama         | 2014-09-25 14:08:37 |
+----+-----------+-------------------+-------------------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------------+
```

My joining code is sadly not working:

```
select  ps.product_reference, 
        ps.productName,
        ps.physicalStock,
        ps.location as 'location'
from productStock as ps
join products ON ps.location = products.location;
```

This is the error I get:

```
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'ps.location' in 'field list'
```

All I want is to show the location for each product by getting location from products table.
this is my show create table for products & productStock:

**mysql> show create table products;**
`------------------------------+
| Table    | Create Table                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       |
+----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| products | CREATE TABLE`products`(`
productID`int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,`
product_reference`varchar(255) NOT NULL,`
brand`varchar(45) NOT NULL,`
model`varchar(45) NOT NULL,`
productName`varchar(255) NOT NULL,`
price`decimal(7,2) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,`
product_description`varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,`
location`varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`productID`,`product_reference`,`model`,`productName`),
  UNIQUE KEY`product_reference`(`product_reference`),
  UNIQUE KEY`model`(`model`),
  UNIQUE KEY`productName`(`productName`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
+----------+---------------------------------------------`

for the productStock table:
**mysql> show create table productStock;**

`+--------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table        | Create Table                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     |
+--------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| productStock | CREATE TABLE`productStock`(`
id`int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,`
productID`int(10) NOT NULL,`
product_reference`varchar(255) NOT NULL,`
productName`varchar(255) NOT NULL,`
brand`varchar(45) NOT NULL,`
model`varchar(45) NOT NULL,`
physicalStock`int(10) unsigned DEFAULT '0',`
lowStockAlert`int(10) DEFAULT '0',`
lastUpdatedBy`varchar(45) NOT NULL,`
lastUpdateDate`timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY`productID`(`productID`),
  UNIQUE KEY`product_reference`(`product_reference`),
  UNIQUE KEY`productName`(`productName`),
  UNIQUE KEY`model`(`model`),
  CONSTRAINT`productStock_ibfk_1`FOREIGN KEY (`productID`) REFERENCES`products`(`productID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT`productStock_ibfk_2`FOREIGN KEY (`product_reference`) REFERENCES`products`(`product_reference`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT`productStock_ibfk_3`FOREIGN KEY (`productName`) REFERENCES`products`(`productName`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT`productStock_ibfk_4`FOREIGN KEY (`model`) REFERENCES`products`(`model`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
+--------------+------------------------------------------`

Comment: You need to join on a column that exists in both tables and just select the location: `inner join products p on ps.productID = p.productID`

Comment: you mean a column exist on both table ,so mean JOIN work with foreigner key column ?

Comment: Correct. productID looks like a foreign key to me.

Comment: yes productID is a foreign key ,by the way is it possible to create a nono unique foreigner key column ? like in my case many products going to be stored in 'Container 1'  and so many products will be stored in Container 1 and I can't reference this column because it's not unique.

Answer (score 0):

Well unfortunately your query is wrong.

There is no `location` column in the `ps` table as you have declared, so you cannot use it as the key for joining the two tables together.

Try this and use `product_reference` as your joining key, as it exists in both tables:

```
SELECT  p.product_reference, 
        p.productName,
        ps.physicalStock,
FROM products AS p
INNER JOIN productStock AS ps ON ps.product_reference = p.product_reference;
```

As another hint: There is redundancy in your `productStock` table, e.g. `productName`, `brand`, `model` can be retrieved from the `product` table and should be dropped from the `productStock` table.

Comment: regarding the new query not working with me, about the redundancy productName,brand,model are foreigner key getting there data from the products table .